# automate: finding non-used servers from a list of servers

Tags: linux, cluster-computing

i have access to a few linux clusters at school.  sometimes they are busy and sometimes they are not.  i usually log into each machine manually, use the "top" command to see if the server is busy (to see if both cores are used).  from there, i execute my program to use some servers that are free to run my computations.

what i'd like to do is to automate this process with a script.  suppose i have a list of servers, say server1 ... server N.  I'd like to log into each of these servers sequentially, run some command (top?), and output a list of servers that are unused (or output the top two processes, showing cpu %, for each server).

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many of the folks here are lucky to get a single machine to play on. :) I think the bash-hackers on superuser.com will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.  Here is my script for anyone that is interested:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

out=avail.txt
rm -rf ~/$out
minLoad=1
for h in $(cat ~/listofservers.txt); do
    ##w | head -1 | cut -d : -f 5 - | cut -d "," -f 2 -
    load=`ssh username@$h uptime | cut -d : -f 5 - | cut -d "," -f 2 -`
    comparison=`expr $load \< $minLoad`
    if [ comparison ]; then
        echo "$h" >> ~/$out
        ##echo "$load" >> ~/$out
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question made me curious. After voting to close it, I found the `w` command.

If you were to do something like

```
echo Host: host
ssh vinh@host w
```

in a script, with one pair of lines for each host you'd like to visit, you could get roughly what you wanted. You could finesse it a bit with `head -1` on the output from `w` to see only the load line.

---

**Update**, improved:

```
for h in host1 host2 host3; do
echo host: $h `ssh vinh@$h w | head -1`
done
```

**Update**, improved some more:

```
for h in host1 host2 host3; do
echo host: $h `ssh vinh@$h uptime`
done
```

Comment: ...or you could use `uptime` instead of `w | head -1` ;)